Intuitively why is pairwise summation less error than naive summation
In numpy sum documentation https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html
It mentions that instead of naive summation it use pairwise summation for better error rate
I am confused on why pairwise summation is better for reducing error
Naive Summation
In naive summation, numbers are added sequentially giving average error of O(sqrt(N)) and worst case O(N)
sum=(((x1+x2)+x3)+…+xn)

Pairwise Summation has average error of O(log(sqrt(N))) and worst case of O(logN)
From google, pairwise improves on naive summation by dividing the list of numbers into pairs, summing each pair, and then recursively summing the results. The process is as follows:

Initial Pairing: Start with the original list of numbers.
{x1,x2,x3,x4,…,xn}
{x1​,x2​,x3​,x4​,…,xn​}

Sum Pairs: Sum the numbers in pairs.
{(x1+x2),(x3+x4),…}
{(x1​+x2​),(x3​+x4​),…}

Recursive Summation: Repeat the process with the sums from the previous step until a single sum remains.
{((x1+x2)+(x3+x4)),…}
{((x1​+x2​)+(x3​+x4​)),…}


Can someone explain the intuition on where is the improvement?
For example
Lets use the following number, say that the mantissa is 3
1.01x10^10 + 1.01x10-10 + 1.01x10^10 + 1.01x10-10

Naive addition
(((1.01x10^10 + 1.01x10-10) + 1.01x10^10) + 1.01x10-10)
(((1.01x10^10 + 1.01x10^10) + 1.01x10-10)
(((2.02x10^10 + 1.01x10-10)
2.02x10^10

Pairwise summation
(1.01x10^10 + 1.01x10-10) + (1.01x10^10 + 1.01x10-10)
1.01x10^10  + 1.01x10^10 
2.02x10^10

Both result in 2.02x10^10

Do the algebra treating every value as value±ε and see how the epsilons accumulate versus cancelling out

Purely as an intuition: You know how floating point numbers have a fixed number of bits in their mantissa (decimal places, if you will), right? And therefore adding a small number to a big one (in magnitude) discards the lowest bits from the small number, resulting in rounding errors. In the naive approach, the partial sum grows, so as you go through the input values, the rounding error on each addition grows. In pairwise sums, all values grow at a similar pace. Of course this doesn't account for alternating signs but it should serve as a starting point

The error is directly related to the length of the longest chain of operation (because the partial sum get big compared to newly added numbers). In the naive sum algorithm, the chain is maximal. With the pairwise summation it is O(log n) (note O(log sqrt n) is O(0.5 log n)). There are better algorithm like the Kahan-sum or even better, though it is difficult to implement efficiently these algorithm (but possible).

You can find information on several old research papers. You can also find some information on Wikipedia. Please read that.

If you want a simple example where the naive sum is not great, just pick a sequence of 1 billion of pi ~= 3.14159265358979 numbers. When the lasts items are added, the partial sum is approximately psum ~= 3141592653.58979 while the last item is pi and psum is ~1e9 times bigger so most digits of pi will be discarded when doing the normalization. With the pair sum, the value is (almost) doubled every time and added value are of the same order of magnitude in this case (nearly perfect one).

Re “ Pairwise Summation has… worst case of O(logN)”: Where did you get this? Consider −2^1023, 0, 2^1023, 2^1023. Pairwise summation produces ∞. The mathematical sum is 2^1023. That is an error of ∞.

Re “From google”: Google does not, to my knowledge, publish information on this topic. Its search engine provides information about other web pages that do. When referring to a source of information, give a URL and/or bibliographic information for it, such as title, author, and other information enabling other people to find the document.

The numpy page you link to says pairwise summation has a better result “in many use-cases.” For a use case of non-negative values spread over a common interval, a reason is the intermediate sums are generally smaller than those of sequential summation, so the rounding errors are smaller. But there are use cases for which this does not hold, as in my example above.

@SteveSummit Pairwise addition also performs N - 1 additions, it is a reordering of parenthesis, the number of additions do not change.

@user25664889 Ack! You're right, of course. Thanks. Comment deleted.

Pairwise summation is not more accurate than 'naive' summation, it depends on the series. Let T_i be the result of the ith addition and u the machine precision. Then an error bound is u (|T_1| + ... + |T_(n - 1)|).
So for naive summation,
T_1 = x_1 + x_2
T_2 = T_1 + x_3
T_3 = T_2 + x_4

For pairwise summation
T_1 = x_1 + x_2
T_2 = x_3 + x_4
T_3 = T_1 + T_2

Background
Let us first look at how we should quantify errors.
Suppose an apple ways 250g, but we measure 249g. If we take the difference, we get an error of 1. This is called the absolute error If we do the same measurement but write down the answer in kg, the error is 0.001.
A solution to this would be to divide by the result: (250 - 249) / 250 = 0.004, (0.25 - 0.249) / 0.25 = 0.004. This is called the relative error. Equivalently, 249 = 250 * (1 - 0.004), so if approximation x' is equal to x(1 + delta), we say |delta| is the relative error.
Floating point addition has small relative error, but not small absolute error, and that is vital to the precision of evaluating sums. To be a bit more precise about the behaviour of IEEE-754 floating point numbers: We write fl(x + y) for the floating point approximation to the true sum x + y. For 32-bit reals we have fl(x + y) = (x + y)(1 + delta) for delta < 2^(-24) and for 64-bit reals the delta is at most 2^(-53).
Intuition
Floating point addition is accurate relative to the result. So we accumulate errors proportional to the partial sums. The smaller the partial sums, the smaller the error.
